# Set Recordset Type of QueryDef via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I can set the Recordset Type of a select query in Access (2002) by opening the query in design view, opening its property sheet, and changing the Recordset Type property to one of three values:

- Dynaset
- Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)
- Snapshot

I can't figure out how to set the property through VBA, though.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Why do you think it's important to do so?

Comment: We have a client who wanted to have direct access to their tables to write their own queries, etc.  We tried to talk them out of it (we provide front-end apps that provide them appropriate access to that backend data), but they were adamant.  Anyway, I wanted a way to provide them direct read-only access through their full version of Access, but still allow them read-write privileges through our interface.  Since we are currently using Access .mdb's on the backend, we were limited in how we could implement such a system.

Comment: @Fenton: Coincidentally, it was one of your answers on another forum that led us to this solution; ie, using snapshot queries in place of linked tables (http://www.accessmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/access-externaldata/16362/Is-it-possible-to-force-a-Linked-Table-to-be-Read#Xns9CF6D8726F9F7f99a49ed1d0c49c5bbb27420913690) ..... So, thanks ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about this:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("test", "select * from atable")
qdf.Properties.Append qdf.CreateProperty("RecordsetType", dbByte, 2)
```

Comment: You're the man Remou!  Answered that so quickly I couldn't accept it right away!  90 seconds of SO.com > 30 minutes of Googling....

Comment: @mwolfe: He's amazing..not to mention the 1260 answers and only 1 question...to which he replied himself. Discouraging ;-)