# Control Rights to Linked Tables in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm afraid I already know the answer to this, but I'm checking with the community in case there's something I don't know about....

Is it possible to have the MS Access table linking feature control rights to linked tables? Secifically, can FE.accdb have read/write privileges on BE_A.accdb, but read-only links to BE_B.accdb (without making BE_B.accdb entirely R/O)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

Quoting David Fenton from a [post earlier this year on another forum](http://www.accessmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/access-externaldata/16362/Is-it-possible-to-force-a-Linked-Table-to-be-Read#Xns9CF6D8726F9F7f99a49ed1d0c49c5bbb27420913690):

> One way would be to remove the linked
>   tables, and create queries to replace
>   them (you could use the same name for
>   the query as the corresponding linked
>   tables), and use a connect string in
>   the query and set the recordset type
>   to snapshot, which will be read-only
>   by default.

I just recently had occasion to do this myself.  I asked a related question about setting the querydef recordset type to snapshot via VBA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685261/set-recordset-type-of-querydef-via-vba).

You can adapt the following code to do what you need:

```
Sub ReadOnlyLink(MDBPath As String, TblName As String, SrcTblName As String)
Dim q As DAO.QueryDef
    Set q = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(TblName, "SELECT * FROM " & SrcTblName & _
                                              " IN """ & MDBPath & """")
    q.Properties.Append q.CreateProperty("RecordsetType", dbByte, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect a postiive answer (as you may have guessed from the original phrasing). I don't know if my need is strong enough to justify doing it, but now I know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but it's too long for comments. Thoughts sparked by the answer I accepted.

It seems that it should be possible to use this for user-level "security":

- Set up a BE
- Set up a distributable FE with deliberately broken links
- in the FE startup, get user name (API calls)
- Run user name through a Select Case, re-linking as either real table or querydef as appropriate. Might be even better to do it with a user name -> role lookup before the Select.

Hmmm. Have to think about that some more.... Not bulletproof, but not really intended to be. More a way of dividing responsibility for updates to the users that are the respective domain experts. Don't know if it's really justified.

Comment: I think the Access development team's position is that security (and user access to data) is a back-end issue, and if you need to do this kind of thing, you have to use a database engine that provides security and access controls. That could be Jet (MDB format), or SQL Server or whatever. ACCDB has nothing to offer in this regard at all (ignore the silly database passwords, which are nothing more than security theater). So maybe you need to reconsider your back-end database.

Comment: Don't have a choice about the back end at this point--client requirement that's further up their priority list than this access control is. I'd much rather have a SQL Server BE....