# Change Access Query Type Dynamically in VBA from a Pass Through (ODBC) Query to a regular Select Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am interested in using a Microsoft Access Query dynamically, sometimes as a Pass Through query using ODBC to get to a remote SQL Server and sometimes as a local Select query to get to a table inside the same Access database. However, the QueryDef.Type property is read-only and I can't figure out how to change it.

So in code it looks like:

```
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDB.QueryDefs("qrySubForm1")

'this line turns the qd.Type property to dbQSQLPassThrough automatically I believe
qd.Connect = "ODBC;--connectionstring--"  

qd.SQL = "Select * from SomeRemoteTable"

'populate the subform with the results of the Pass Through query
SubForm1.SourceObject = "Query.qrySubForm1" 

'Intent: change to regular select query.
qd.Type = dbQSelect   ' Error: read-only property

qd.SQL = "Select * from ALocalTable"

' now change the SubForm to show results of the local query
SubForm1.SourceObject = "Query.qrySubForm1"
```

The QueryDef Type property is one of the values in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192931.aspx) enum.

If I switch between two local queries, or between two pass-through queries it works fine. It's only when I try to switch between a pass-through query and a local query that I'm having trouble.

**Update:**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685372/2363207) answer to another SO question seems to suggest that I can add a property to the query definition, but I'm not sure if that would apply in the case of the "Type."

Comment: By it's nature, a pass-thru query has an ODBC connection. That is not required for a local query as you can simply execute the SQL. Why don't you just grab the SQL (like: currentdb.querydefs("passthru").SQL) then execute (but not using that prior connection)?

Comment: If the two queries have different SQL (as your code suggests), I would just keep both queries. And only switch `SubForm1.SourceObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to delete and create the QueryDef.

add this before changing to local table:

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, qd.name
Set qd= MyDB.CreateQueryDef(qd.name)
qd.SQL = "Select * from ALocalTable;"
qd.close
```

and if you want to go back to passthrough:

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, qd.name
Set qd= MyDB.CreateQueryDef(qd.name)
qd.connect = GET_CONNECTION_STRING
qd.SQL = "Select * from SomeRemoteTable;"
qd.close
```

for update queries set "qd.ReturnsRecords = false"

Comment: It will be next week before I can confirm this works, but logically I think it will work fine. I didn't think to just wipe out the query definition and re-create it. Thanks!